# Show transition screen fields on issue screen

Tags: workflow, screen, field, jira, transition

Is it possible to show on an issue screen the value of transition screen fields ? (on the right side for example such as date fields)

Example :

I have a field called "initial date" in a transition of my workflow, and I wonder if it was possible to show it on the right side of my issue's screen ?

Thanks a lot,

Christophe

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can add this field to default screen on this issue type and if value of this field isn't empty, should show on view issue page.

On the right side of issue will show always all fields type: user and date in default configuration.